# Which files should I remove from /var/log directory to free space in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, disk-usage, logging, storage

I have installed Ubuntu 16.04 two days ago on a 158GB HDD and it is already showing 128GB space is used. After checking the drive I've found that the directory `/var/log` is occupying 116GB and it is constantly expanding its size,

Size of different files in `/var/log` is :

- syslog -- 21GB
- syslog1 -- 36GB
- kern.log -- 57GB

Now I see this problem is faced by many Ubuntu users and there are different questions have already been asked [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/100004/how-can-i-free-space-from-a-massive-39-5gb-var-log-folder), [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239455/how-do-i-stop-var-log-kern-log-1-from-consuming-all-my-disk-space), [3](https://askubuntu.com/questions/795438/log-file-eating-up-whole-space-in-ubuntu-16-04-lts-fix) and [4](https://askubuntu.com/questions/863995/my-var-log-folder-is-taking-too-much-space). But I don't know which folder I should delete.

Furthermore, I am using HP Probook 440 G3.

Help in this regard is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You don't want to delete those files... yet. You need to review them to see what activity is occurring on your computer that 'causes the log files to get so large. In `terminal`, type `more syslog*` or `more kern.log`.

Comment: @heynnema but how can I able to monitor the activity? I means list is too long which I am not able to understand. So what to do now?

Comment: In `terminal`, use `tail -f /var/log/syslog` or `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` to monitor syslog/kern.log in real time.

Comment: @heynnema these are screenshots of syslog and kern.log activities:

[syslog](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3s5jh17qovl9j13/Screenshot%20from%202017-02-05%2020-36-00.png?dl=0)

[kern.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yln0v5ixfaz7bkc/Screenshot%20from%202017-02-05%2020-40-27.png?dl=0)

Comment: See my updated answer, below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want to delete those files... yet. You need to review them to see what activity is occurring on your computer that causes the log files to get so large. In `terminal`, type `more /var/log/syslog*` or `more /var/log/kern.log`.

If the files are too large, or you have trouble interpreting what you're seeing, monitor them in real time... in `terminal`, use `tail -f /var/log/syslog` or `tail -f /var/log/kern.log`. You'll probably see one error that repeats itself over and over.

In reviewing the log files, you have a problem with your video subsystem. See [Nvidia GeForce 930M driver and PCI bus error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/748078/nvidia-geforce-930m-driver-and-pci-bus-error) for a similar problem/fix. Also see https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-Software-and-How-To-Questions/Error-Spam-AER-id-00e5-PCIe-Bus-Error-severity-Corrected/td-p/5933687 and https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1521173. Google "device id 8086:9d15" if you need more info yet.

In `terminal`...

- `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
- add `pci=nomsi` OR `pci=noaer` *(which ever one fixes your problem)* to

  - GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash `pci=nomsi`"
  - or
  - GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash `pci=noaer`"
- save and quit gedit
- `sudo update-grub`
- `reboot`

Comment: these are screenshots of syslog and kern.log activities:

[syslog](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3s5jh17qovl9j13/Screenshot%20from%202017-02-05%2020-36-00.png?dl=0)
 and
 [kern.log](https://www.dropbox.com/s/yln0v5ixfaz7bkc/Screenshot%20from%202017-02-05%2020-40-27.png?dl=0)

Comment: but I don't have a Nvidia graphics card in my machine?

Comment: @MuhammadToseef see my update.

Comment: let me check it.

Comment: no success :( I've tried

Comment: Did you reboot after each edit and update-grub? You tried both edits, and neither one works? In terminal, type `grep -i cmdline /etc/default/grub` and show me the output.

Comment: OMG it works.  The error messages aren't showing anymore after checking by `tail -f /var/log/syslog`. But now how can I delete old folders which are occupying so much space?

Comment: Which one did you use... nomsi or noaer? In terminal, `sudo rm -i /var/log/filename`.

Comment: I've tried both ones but the second one works, `noare`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/53082/discussion-between-muhammad-toseef-and-heynnema).