# Hard drive is full help

Tags: hard-drive

I moved all my files to another Hdd (video,photos,docs etc)cleaned up 120gb of a 1TB HDD. Still had 800gb floating around on my HDD.

I have found in my VAR, Log, 2 text files 757.7Gb syslog and 40.3Gb syslog.

Can i delete these file or how can i stop them from fill my Hdd.
[image: syslog text file]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to find out what's filling up `syslog` because there could be something that keeps happening to fill it up like that, but other than that, you can delete them (reboot after deleting to regain the disk space).

Comment: Yes it would be good to find the culprit filling the hdd, any ideas how to. can i delete the syslog.gz

Comment: Read some of the logfiles that take up so much space: `tail /path/to/logfile.log`. You stop the logifle from filling your HDD by solving the problem that is getting logged about.

Comment: `sudo rm /var/log/syslog*.gz` should get rid of all of the `.gz` files. `sudo rm /var/log/syslog*` will remove the non-`.gz` `syslog` files as well. Don't forget to reboot afterwards to actually see the free space, though.

Comment: Please edit your question to include the output of `tail -n 20 /var/log/syslog`, so we can see why your syslog is filling up so fast.

Comment: Thanks All ,have 908gb free space on 1Tb hdd. Now to find the culprit.

Comment: `sudo du -hd1 /` and start digging. Happy hunting...

Comment: Possibly related: [Which files should I remove from /var/log directory to free space in Ubuntu 16.04?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/880106/which-files-should-i-remove-from-var-log-directory-to-free-space-in-ubuntu-16-0/880124#880124)

Comment: Feb  7 19:41:28 milan-MS-7758 kodi.desktop[3099]: extern "Python": function Cryptography_rand_status() called, but @ffi.def_extern() was not called in the current subinterpreter.  Returning 0.   This is what is filling my Hdd. when i exit Kodi it hangs on the screen.

Comment: Well there's your problem!  They can probably help you in the Kodi forums.  Good luck.