# Kernel panic after updating kernel on 16.04

Tags: boot, 16.04, kernel

Some days ago I asked a [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/880106/which-files-should-i-remove-from-var-log-directory-to-free-space-in-ubuntu-16-0/880124?noredirect=1#comment1370408_880124) about getting free space and found a solution. But after solving this issue my system freezes on a frequent basis in Ubuntu 16.04. I have tried a [solution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/761706/ubuntu-15-10-and-16-04-keep-freezing-randomly/789092#789092) from another question asked on Ask Ubuntu but I ran into another problem - kernel panic after reboot.

At start this message is showing:

```
KASLR disabled: 'kaslr' not on cmdline (hibernation selected).
```

And after some time these three screens ([1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/6qm0ro3uyn9kx90/booterror1.jpg?dl=0),[2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/qle00yu4vjjmvta/booterror2.jpg?dl=0),[3](https://www.dropbox.com/s/hgezxgebb6n9t45/booterror3.jpg?dl=0)) are appearing.

I am using HP Probook 440 G3 with dual boot with windows 10. I have checked Windows and it is booting perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Hopefully you have an earlier linux kernel installed that does not panic:

- Press left shift key after power on to reach boot menu as described in the comments: [grub2 boot menu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/16042/how-to-get-to-the-grub-menu-at-boot-time)
- select earlier ubuntu linux kernel, with lower version number, than the topmost.
- when the earlier Ubuntu linux kernel works as wanted, then remove the buggy one with synaptic package manager.
- But beware: remove the right one and do not install the update to it afterwards.

Hope to be of help!

Comment: thanks. I've already found the solution from [here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/2793/how-do-i-remove-old-kernel-versions-to-clean-up-the-boot-menu)