# Increasingly Filling Disk Space - Fixed by reboot

Tags: disk, disk-usage

My new Ubuntu computer (running 16.10) fills disk space until it's full. Executing `du -h --max-depth 1` on the `/` directory shows very little space used (like 30 GiBs at most).

When I reboot, this issue is resolved.

Comment: How did you know your disk is full?

Comment: "df -h"  returns 100%. Programs stop working. Etc.

Comment: Please paste it in you OP.

Comment: Will do next time it happens

Comment: What brand/model. We have seen this with some Asus. Asus x555u w/o pci=nomsi - space issue on drive and runaway log files filling drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2327103&page=3 and
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2327570

Comment: System76 Onyx. I have a ticket open with them but I wanted to see if it was an easy fix or known issue here. Drive is an m2 ssd.

Comment: Use the `Disk Usage Analyzer` to find where your disk space is going. Look at the size of the log files in /var/log. If they're huge, `more /var/log/syslog` to see what's filling them up... probably the same error over and over. See http://askubuntu.com/questions/880106/which-files-should-i-remove-from-var-log-directory-to-free-space-in-ubuntu-16-0/880124#880124

Comment: And you can run `sudo du -h / --max-depth=1 | sort -h` which will show you which folders are taking up the most room at the bottom of the list.  That should help you get a better understanding of where all your space is going.  Ignore the `/` at the bottom as that is all the space of all folders added together.

Comment: When I was full, I only got 100 GiB out of 500 using `du` (unless I was looking at it wrong) would `.xsession_errors` purge on reboot by chance?

Comment: I've been using linux for awhile, so my first step was du (as per OP) I did notice when I was at about 120/500 that my .xsession_errors file was 70GiB, so I fixed the issue (I was missing `feh` which I use once a minute in my i3 config to change my background)